# Android Activity management

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

I have one question in mind for **activity management**. Suppose I have 4 activities say for example A1,A2,A3,A4. Now A1 have one button which start activity A2. A2 have 2 buttons which start  either A3 or A4, A3 have  2 buttons which start activity  A4 and A1. A4 have 3 buttons to sart activity A1,A2,A3 I do not use finish method in any of this activity. So now user click any of the activity any of the button than check the activity ,that is this already in back ground? If yes than this activity would not generate new instance and start activity which is **already in background**. otherwise it create new insistence.

Comment: In short I just want to know that is activity already in background,and if it is.. than how to get it bring to front..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this behaviour by including the [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) in your `Intent`'s flags and then just calling `startActivity(intent)` like you normally would.

Comment: Would not using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` make more sense in this case? As user may return to other activities that were at the top of now launching activity.

Comment: @shoerat You're right, I was confused. It's early morning for me :-). Your comment came in after I already fixed that.

Comment: @Barend thanks for answer.. currently your answer is to good. After my implementation I will accept it. +1...

Answer (score 1):

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You can search "android:lunchMode" by Google. 
Then you will get the anwser.

Comment: if you set android:lunchMode = singleTask in the AndroidManifest.xml,the activities in the activtity stack will be the Singleton. when you start an activity which has had in the activtity stack,the system will not create a new instance, it will put it on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the button is clicked in any activity, it creates the new instance of the activity irrespective of the fact the activity is already on the activity stack. Since new Intent is fired every time, it opens new activity.
When we press back button then only it goes to the already opened activity from the stack.

Comment: thanks!! I know this but. if there is so many activity connected each other than it is possible to already created in back ground..