# startActivity causes onCreate()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have application and when I navigate back using `Intent` and `startActivity()`, `views` are null, `onCreate()` is called and activities are re-initialized. Why is that and how to bypass it?

I navigate back to activity like that:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          if (this.getClass() == XXX.class) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, YYY.class);
                startActivity(i); //<-- activity restarts
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

I use ActionbarSherlock, so I have activity with ActionBar initialization and every single activity just extends it. The way I navigate back to activity is described in this activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
    initUIComponents();
    setListeners();
    resetProgress();


}
```

and initUI() initializes UI.

**EDIT**

What I mean, how can I go back to previously created `activity` (not the one that is called via `onBackPressed`) and not recreate it? I use `startActivity`(), but apparently it recreates the whole thing

Comment: Could you include a little code please to help us try and assist you?

Comment: You're not really navigating *back* though if you call startActivity...

Comment: Yes, my question is, what is correct way?

Comment: The correct Way is just to call `finish()`. That would close (destroy) current Activity and go back to the previous Activity unless You call `finish()` when start this Activity

Comment: But I don't want to go to previous activity.

Comment: So I misunderstood question. Go back I mean as go to previous activity :). If You just want to go to another activity, so Your code looks OK. startActivity just create another isntance of Activity so, all views have to be initialized again. If You want go back to the specified Activity on the stack, so You have to finish all activities above it

Comment: Although i am not sure about the solution, but try removing `super.onBackPressed()`, since here you are handling the back press event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that when you press back, you want to show the previous screen, then you don't have to do it in your code. Android Runtime internally maintains the stack, and will take care of showing the **last-shown-activity** when you press back. No need to handle it via `onBackPressed()`

However, if you want something other than this default action, *that* is when you should use `onBackPressed()`. Else, just let Android handle it.

So, in your application, if `Activity 1` calls `Activity 2`, and user presses back, then the default action would be to show `Activity 1` again. Don't override the `onBackPressed()` method

**Edit:**
For a custom flow of activities, you'll have to build the logic yourself. You need to override `onRestart()` in `Activity 1`, and `onStop()` in `Activity 3`. That way, `onCreate` won't be called again. By your logic, I mean, flags to keep track of which activity you're in, checking those flags, and calling the desired activity from there.

**Edit 2:**
This previous SO question, answers what you need:

[Android Activity management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456974/android-activity-management) , which suggests setting the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) on the intent, and then calling `startActivity()`

Check out Android activity stack management using Intent flags for other stack reordering options: [Stack management](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: I mean, I have Activity 1, I go to Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3, and then I want to go to Activity 1, not navigate all the way back through activity tree.

Comment: Edited the answer. You need to override onRestart()

Comment: How would it prevent reinitialization of activity?

Comment: Checkout the SO post I've mentioned in the answer.